# need help with drupal arrays

Tags: theming

my array for $var gave me the following $var dump

```
stdClass Object

    (
        [vid] => 71
        [uid] => 1
        [title] => dr1
        [log] => 
        [status] => 1
        [comment] => 1
        [promote] => 1
        [sticky] => 0
        [nid] => 71
        [type] => doc_upload
        [language] => und
        [created] => 1378359025
        [changed] => 1378359025
        [tnid] => 0
        [translate] => 0
        [revision_timestamp] => 1378359025
        [revision_uid] => 1
        [body] => Array
            (
            )

        [field_upload] => Array
            (
                [und] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [fid] => 59
                                [display] => 1
                                [description] => 
                                [uid] => 1
                                [filename] => drupal-7.23.zip
                                [uri] => public://documents/drupal-7.23.zip
                                [filemime] => application/zip
                                [filesize] => 3646168
                                [status] => 1
                                [timestamp] => 1378359025
                            )

                    )

            )
```

i need to take the value of **[uri]...** (indicated above) in a variable. Plz help

Answer (score 2):

$uri = $var->field_upload[und][0][uri];

For object you need to use the notation '->' for tracing the object and $var is the variable which gave you the array .

Comment: pls check updated answer